# Multi thread Semaphores using C

Tags: c, operating-system, semaphore

I want to make sure that I have done correct according to the given question. the question is  to make a simple series of programs that prints to the screen the following string - "I love OS class". To do this we will have 4 processes, each one will only print 1 word.  we will start all of them, and they will wait on the appropriate signal from the correct process.  The process that prints "class" will be waiting on the the process that prints "OS" to signal it, the "OS" print process will wait on the "love " process, and the "love" process will wait on the "I" process.

I have come up with following code but I'm not sure if my logic is correct or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sem_t mutex;

void* thread(void* arg){
  //wait
  sem_wait(&mutex);
  printf("I \n");

  //wait
  sleep(2);
  
  //critical section
  sem_post(&mutex);
  printf("Love \n");
  
  //wait
  sem_wait(&mutex);
  printf("OS \n");
  
  //critical section
  sleep(2);
  sem_post(&mutex);
  printf("Class \n");
  

}

int main(){
   sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
   
    pthread_t t1,t2,t3,t4;
    
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,thread,NULL);
    sleep(2);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,thread,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t3,NULL,thread,NULL);
    sleep(2);
    pthread_create(&t4,NULL,thread,NULL);
    
    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);
    pthread_join(t3,NULL);
    pthread_join(t4,NULL);
    
    sem_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

my output shows:

```
I 
Love 
I 
Love 
OS 
Class 
I 
Love 
OS 
Class 
I 
Love 
OS 
Class 
OS 
Class
```

Comment: So what did your testing show?

Comment: As written every thread will print every string, as there is no `if` of any kind in the thread function.  The semaphore operations only affect *when* the code gets executed by that thread, not *whether*.

Comment: @kaylum i have updated my output.

Comment: *but I'm not sure if my logic is correct or not*. Then you should be able to answer that yourself. The output is not what you want so obviously the logic is not correct.

Comment: Oh, it's flawed - it has sleep() calls for no good reason.  To serialize four threads in a defined order, you need three semaphores.